# OData binding with multiple keys

Tags: javascript, data-binding, odata, sapui5, hana

I am having a problem binding a table to an OData service. I used OData services before and everything worked fine but now I got to a point, where I don't know why my code is not working.

Normally I bind data from a model with a path to the specific data like this:

```
<Table id="idTable" inset="false" items="{path:'objdetails>/DETAILSet'}">
```

Now my dataset has a path like this:

```
'objdetails>/DETAILSet(key1='val1', key2='val2', key3='val3, key4='val4', key5='val5')/SECONDSet'
```

Everytime I try to bind my table to this path I get the error, that should be a "," where the val1 starts. So for example val1 = 00001, I get the error that the first 0 should be a ",".

Has someone had the same problem? Is my code correct or do have have to do it in another way with those odata services?

I searched on for similar problems on the web, but couldn't find something like this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you print the contents of your model ? Are you applying a filter with keys :objdetails>/DETAILSet(key1='val1', key2='val2', key3='val3, key4='val4', key5='val5')/SECONDSet ?

Comment: I assume that this is just a typo: key3='val3, key4='val4' There is a ' missing after val3

Answer (score 0):

You did not post the second example completely, but I assume that you are using a static binding like follows:

```
<Table id="idTable" inset="false" items="{path: 'objdetails>/DETAILSet(key1='val1', key2='val2', key3='val3', key4='val4', key5='val5')/SECONDSet'}">
```

The error is correct, as the parser found the inverted coma (') at your first key and assumes that the value of property path is complete and the next value follows, e.g. another path. You can use the following static binding as the path is not required:

```
<Table id="idTable" inset="false" items="{objdetails>/DETAILSet(key1='val1', key2='val2', key3='val3', key4='val4', key5='val5')/SECONDSet}">
```

Normally you would set the binding in your controller, e.g. by setting a binding context. But if it should be statically you could also try:

```
<Table id="idTable" inset="false" items="{path: 'objdetails>/DETAILSet(key1=\'val1\', key2=\'val2\', key3=\'val3\', key4=\'val4\', key5=\'val5\')/SECONDSet'}">
```